# Pandas Dataframe: List type column created from comparisons between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Considering the two dataframes below, where in `df` the column `USER` represent a user and `ANTENNA_ID` represent antennas that users used to make phone calls and in `df2` the column `USER` also represent a user and `PRESUMED_RESIDENCE` indicates the antenna closest to the user's home:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'USER':[1,2,3,1,1,2],
                   'ANTENNA_ID': ['SJDR1', 'LD', 'LD', 'LD', 'TR', 'SVM']})


df2 = pd.DataFrame({'USER': [1,2,3],
                    'PRESUMED_RESIDENCE': ['SJDR1', 'LD', 'LD']})
```

I need to create another dataframe containing the `USER` column, the `PRESUMED_RESIDENCE` of `df2` column and other column containing the locations where users made calls that are different from their `PRESUMED_RESIDENCE`.

```
USER | PRESUMED RESIDENCE  | CALL_LOC
  1  |        SJDR1        | LD, TR
  2  |         LD          | SVM
  3  |         LD          | Nan
```

what I've managed to imagine so far is far from the expected result, as can be seen below:

```
df2['CALL_LOC'] = np.where(df.USER.values==df2.USER.values, df.ANTENNA_ID.values, np.nan)
df2
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about removing the `PRESUMED_RESIDENCE` from the list of `CALL_LOC`, it's fairly straightforward in pandas.

```
merged = pd.merge(df, df2, left_on="USER", right_on="USER")

print(merged.to_string())
>    USER ANTENNA_ID PRESUMED_RESIDENCE
0     1      SJDR1              SJDR1
1     1         LD              SJDR1
2     1         TR              SJDR1
3     2         LD                 LD
4     2        SVM                 LD
5     3         LD                 LD

grouped = merged.groupby("USER").agg(
    {"PRESUMED_RESIDENCE": min, "ANTENNA_ID": list}
)

print(grouped.to_string())

>      PRESUMED_RESIDENCE       ANTENNA_ID
USER                                    
1                 SJDR1  [SJDR1, LD, TR]
2                    LD        [LD, SVM]
3                    LD             [LD]
```

You could also use the `USER` as the index.

If you want to remove the `PRESUMED_RESIDENCE` from the `ANTENNA_ID`, you can do it as a second step by iterating through the rows.

If you want to do that during the construction of the pd.DataFrame, you can modify each group of the `groupby` object.

Comment: Thanks, very useful!